# How to catch a Database insertion (run time) error in typescript and write a suitable test case in chai?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js, chai

This is my try block:

```
try {
    User.create({
            firstName: "Mahesh",
            lastName: "Das"
   });
}
```

Here, I need to catch the DB insertion (runtime) error.
Am using postgres as Database and Sequelize to perform operations.
I also need to write a test case for the same using chai.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `expect.to.throw` (https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw)?

Comment: Yes. But, firstly I should be catching that error. Am not able to catch that error.

Comment: I believe if you're catching the error, you want be able to test if the error is thrown. Do you have a catch block? Is your question how to catch a specific error, then how to test if that error was caught?

Comment: Yes. My question is, how to catch the db insertion (run-time) error and then, how to test if the error is caught?

Comment: Can you post what the error looks like?

Comment: Hey, sorry I was off for a bit. Am not getting the error as of now. But, I want to be ready with this error handling so that it wouldn't cause problems on a later point of time.

Comment: I assume you know how to draft a catch block. Is your problem that you don't know how to catch the particular DB insertion error?

Comment: Yes. I need help in drafting the catch block for this particular error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other languages, like Java, in JavaScript we can only catch the general error then check that error and handle appropriately.

```js
try {
  ... some code ...
}
catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
    ... handle SyntaxError ...
  }
  else if (err instanceof TypeError) {
    ... handle TypeError ...
  }
  else {
    ... catch everything else ...
  }
}
```

Since you have not provided an example of the error you're trying to catch, I cannot make my example more specific to your case, but the above approach should work for you.

Your test, since you're catching the error, will depend on what happens in the respective catch block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It means a lot.
 I will implement this right away.

Comment: If this answer works for you, please select it as answered.